# Execute commands in try_files on ngnix

Tags: mongodb, caching, nginx, image

is it possible to execute a command when using try_files in nginx?

This is because I log all the requests in mongoDB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can have the try_files access a named location, in the named location you can do whatever you want (fcgi/uwsgi/reverse proxy)...

the bare-bones config would look like this:

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ @named; }

location @named {
  # fcgi/uwsgi/revorse proxy, add necessary directives for what you want to do
}
```

note however, you only get to the named location if the earlier try_files parts don't match (in the example above if there's no file or directory matching the request path)

Comment: Thanks you but what I want to get is that part to run when they match. Is it possible?